# Geometric proof and extension of |a|=|b|=|c|=a+b+c=1 => a=1 or b=1 or c=1

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, alternative-proof

We have $a,b,c\in\mathbb{C}$ verifying $|a|=|b|=|c|=a+b+c=1$, we have to show that $a=1$ or $b=1$ or $c=1$.
That can be rather easily proved using trigonometry formulas.

- Is there a way to prove it by a geometric proof ? (edit : geometry isn't where i'm the best, so please make a detailed answer)
- If we just had $|a|=|b|=|c|=a+b+c=x, x\in\mathbb{R}$, would there still be solutions ? If so, which ones ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume the contrary, i.e. that none of the vectors $a,b,c$ is parallel to the $x$-axes, as in the diagram below:

[image]

Since:
$$x=\angle OAB = \angle OBC$$
$$y=\angle COA = \angle CBA$$
And: $$2x+2y = 360^\circ$$ we have that $x+y=180^\circ$, or that at least one vector is  parallel to the $x$-axes.

Of course, nowhere have we used the actual length, so the claim holds true for all $x$.

Comment: what is the dollar sign in '∠$OBC' ?

Comment: @Hippalectryon - a syntax error. Fixed.

Comment: what is the '∠' sign ? I thought it was 'angle', but here angle(COA)>angle(CBA) so ..

Comment: @Hippalectryon - it is an angle, and the angles are equal since this is an isosceles triangle.

Comment: @Hippalectryon - stretch a line from C to A. Note how the triangles $COA$ and $CBA$ are identical.

Comment: Uh from what i see, |∠COA|>pi/2 and |∠CBA|<pi/2

Comment: @Hippalectryon - a geometric sketch is not meant to be accurate - after all, if we knew a priori what the angles were we would not need a proof. So, I purposely drew a wrong diagram showing a hypothetical case - i.e, that the claim is wrong. I then used that diagram to prove that this situation cannot exist. 
In short, never deduce from a diagram that which is not given.

Answer (score 1):

1. Seen as vectors, we have $a+b+c-1=0$, i.e. concatenating the vectors $a,b,c,-1$ one after the other will give us a *quadrilateral* with equal sides, so one could find a permutation of these vectors such that we get a rhombus, and the vector on side parallel to $-1$ will be the $+1$.
2. Yes, for any $x\in\Bbb C$, if $|a|=|b|=|c|=|x|$ and $a+b+c=x$ then one of $a,b,c$ equals to $x$.

   This can  be seen either directly by the above argument, or just multiply everything by $x$ in the original result.

Comment: Sorry, but i am not really good at geometry; what's a rhombus ?

Comment: A quadrilateral which has equal sides, also called a *diamond* shape, this is both a parallelogram and a deltoid.